# Phonegap vs Rhomobile

Tags: cordova, comparison, rhomobile

I'm starting a new project and one of the objectives is to make a comparison matrix between Phonegap and Rhomobile.

I've been investigating on both platforms, but I'm having trouble finding all the info I need.

What are the things that really set this two apart?

I know everyone has a favorite, but I'm trying to be objective, I need facts about their functionalities!

Comment: You may be interested in [this matrix](http://www.markus-falk.com/mobile-frameworks-comparison-chart/).

Comment: hows the progress? Do you already have a matrix to compare hybrid frameworks?

Comment: Did you choose a framework? I've come to the conclusion that both are equally good. They both have pros/cons, and it's really difficult to choose the right one.

Comment: I'm still working on the matrix but I chose phoneGap because it fits better with my needs, it uses only JS, HTML and CSS and has all the native features I need, without having to program in ruby.